# k8s nodeport does not working for specific node

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to k8s.

I'm testing `NodePort` service with my k8s cluster.
I constructed my k8s cluster with aws EC2 instances using kubespray.
My cluster consists of 1 master and 5 nodes.
Below is my manifest files.

```yaml
# deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-react-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-react-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-react-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-react-app
          image: 10.1.3.245/my-react-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always


# service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-react-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
  selector:
    app: my-react-app
```

Also here is my node ips.

```
# This is from ansible inventory.
node1 ansible_host=10.1.3.58 ip=10.1.3.58
node2 ansible_host=10.1.3.191 ip=10.1.3.191
node3 ansible_host=10.1.3.88 ip=10.1.3.88
node4 ansible_host=10.1.3.74 ip=10.1.3.74
node5 ansible_host=10.1.3.228 ip=10.1.3.228
```

My problem is that among 5 nodes, only 1 node is not accessible. I tested accessibility using curl. For example, `curl 10.1.3.58:31000` works but `curl 10.1.3.74:31000` does not work.
If my understanding is correct, every node should open 31000 port for NodePort service.

Can anyone give any advice?

(Edit1)
Here is the answer of comment

```sh
ubuntu@master1:~$ kubectl get service
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.233.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        9d
my-react-app   NodePort    10.233.8.196   <none>        80:31000/TCP   27h


ubuntu@master1:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master1   Ready      master   9d    v1.19.6
master2   NotReady   master   9d    v1.19.6
node1     Ready      <none>   9d    v1.19.6
node2     Ready      <none>   9d    v1.19.6
node3     Ready      <none>   9d    v1.19.6
node4     Ready      <none>   9d    v1.19.6
node5     Ready      <none>   9d    v1.19.6
```

(Edit2)

```
# curl result
ubuntu@master1:~$ curl -v 10.1.3.74:31000
* Rebuilt URL to: 10.1.3.74:31000/
*   Trying 10.1.3.74...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.1.3.74 port 31000 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.1.3.74 port 31000: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.1.3.74 port 31000: Connection timed out


# recent journalctl result
journalctl -u kubelet -r

Jan 20 14:28:01 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:28:01.383853   24294 setters.go:77] Using node IP: "10.1.3.245"
Jan 20 14:27:51 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:27:51.329070   24294 setters.go:77] Using node IP: "10.1.3.245"
Jan 20 14:27:41 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:27:41.279939   24294 setters.go:77] Using node IP: "10.1.3.245"
Jan 20 14:27:31 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:27:31.227616   24294 setters.go:77] Using node IP: "10.1.3.245"
Jan 20 14:27:25 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:27:25.704775   24294 kubelet_getters.go:176] "Pod status updated" pod="kube-system/kube-controller-manager-m
Jan 20 14:27:25 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:27:25.704533   24294 kubelet_getters.go:176] "Pod status updated" pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-master1" s
Jan 20 14:27:25 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:27:25.703786   24294 kubelet_getters.go:176] "Pod status updated" pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-master1" s
Jan 20 14:27:24 master1 kubelet[24294]: W0120 14:27:24.113350   24294 container_manager_linux.go:954] MemoryAccounting not enabled for pid: 24294
Jan 20 14:27:24 master1 kubelet[24294]: W0120 14:27:24.112644   24294 container_manager_linux.go:951] CPUAccounting not enabled for pid: 24294
Jan 20 14:27:21 master1 kubelet[24294]: I0120 14:27:21.170841   24294 setters.go:77] Using node IP: "10.1.3.245"
```

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get service` ?

Comment: Your understanding about NodePort is correct. Could you please add output @CodeWizard  asked for, also could you add output from `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: @CodeWizard and Jakub I attached your questions

Comment: @bmy4415 From what I see all nodes are ready, are there any differences between these ec2 instances? Could you also check what is the issue when you use `curl -v 10.1.3.74:31000`? Is it connection refused or timeout? Also could you check if there is anything in kubelet logs? You can check it with `journalctl -u kubelet`.

Comment: @Jakub I think there is no differences between ec2 instances. They use same security group. I attached result of `curl -v 10.1.3.74:31000` at question. `curl 10.1.3.74:31000` show timeout. I also attached result of `journalctl -u kubelet -r` to show recent logs.

Comment: 1.I assume all of your kubernetes pods are healthy and running? 2.Any restarts, not working pods when you check with `kubectl get pods`? 3.What is your CNI? 4.Have you changed anything in kubespray configuration? 5.Also could you please verify if kernel ip forwarding is enabled in this not working ec2 instance? You can check it with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, 0 means it's diabled, 1 means it's enabled. More about that [here](https://goteleport.com/blog/troubleshooting-kubernetes-networking/) search for "Kernel IP forwarding".

Comment: 1. All pods are running. 2. `kubectl get pods` shows all pods are running well. 3. I don't know what is CNI and how to check what CNI is installed but I think `calico` is used because files located at `/etc/cni/net.d` have names like `10-calico.conflist`, `calico-kubeconfig`, `calico.conflist.template`. 4. No... I just changed `ansible.cfg` and inventory. 5. ip forwarding is enabled in all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the exact reason for this issue. But when I construct the k8s cluster with `eksctl`, it works. I think there exist some points that I don't know on AWS EC2 / kubespary. Anyway, **`NodePort` service can be accessed from all nodes.**